# AZURE:ProviderIncompatibleException was unhandled by user code

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

While running application on localhost getting the following Exception:
**ProviderIncompatibleException was unhandled by user code.**

The Provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken String.

***Inner Exception:***
**{"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)"}**

Earlier this applcation was running fine, but suddenly statrted to get this error message. The live application hosted which is using the same databse credientails is working fine without any error.

I am using the window azure database. Even the link to manage the database(i.e. database..windows.net)provided in the windows.azure.com is not opening any page... it is showing an error.

Any solution or recommendation will be great help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If it used to work fine I assume this might be caused because you installed VS11 / VS2012. There are a few reports of people having issues connecting to SQL Azure since they installed the new version of Visual Studio: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/vssetup/thread/2d11b6f9-3ada-4682-b643-c721a97af4ba

For most people uninstalling VS11 / VS2012 helped them to get things working again.

Alternatively, you could try changing the connection line to this: **Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;trustServerCertificate=true;** (see Wade's [blogpost](http://www.wadewegner.com/2010/08/using-the-trustservercertificate-property-with-sql-azure-and-entity-framework/)).

Comment: Hi Sandrino, Thank You for the Reply... Following is my connection string  <add name="Amavid"  connectionString="Server=tcp:fgugi9gyy6.database.windows.net,1433;Database=amavid;User ID=user;Password=pass;Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Even the manage link provided on the windows.azure.com site to manage the database is not working.On clicking on the link the page goes for long time processing and at the end shows nothing. Any assistant will be helpful thank you

Comment: Please make sure your data context class's name is Amavid. According to http://mattfrear.com/2011/01/01/system-data-providerincompatibleexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code/, if the names do not match, you will get this error.